# MySQL, Query, php, query

Tags: mysql

I have table quality like this :

```
|id   |poin|
-------------
|B01  |80  |
|B01  |85  |
|B02  |94  |
|B02  |90  |
```

and I want to split poin become two cols like this :

```
|id   | 1st poin | 2nd poin |
-----------------------------
|B01  | 80       | 85       |
|B02  | 94       | 90       |
```

what kind of query to execute? thanks

Comment: Is this table in html and you want to insert it with php to a database?

Comment: GabrielOshiro : I have tried using "GROUP BY id" but the result is only 1st poin.

Comment: select `min(poin)` and `max(poin)` to go along with your group by

Comment: You can't do this, at least with the information you've given so far. A cross-tab query would get you close, but there's no way to get MySQL to put the `B02/94` row before the `B02/90` row while at the same time putting the `B01/80` row before the `B01/85` row. Does your `quality` table have any other columns?

Comment: @Elomar Adam : it was a table from database and I want to show the value with graph jpGraph

Comment: @pala_ But he doesn't always want the min and max in the same place.

Comment: And there's no indication that each `id` will have just two rows.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there's also no indication that he's given it much thought. There are zero alternatives for ordering the results - and the indication that it will just have two rows per id is the fact that he only seems to want two columns

Comment: @EdGibbs: yes I have other columns, column name is "dateSampling", that column to identified when the poin was inputed

Comment: Kayana, what should happen if an `id` has three or four or five `poin` values?

Comment: @EdGibbs it should become 3rd poin, 4th poin, etc

Comment: Ah, in that case you should `SELECT id, poin FROM quality ORDER BY id, dateSampling` and then assemble the jpGraph points in your presentation code. What you're trying to do is cross-tabulate with an unknown number of columns, and a SQL query must have a predefined number of columns.

Comment: @EdGibbs here is the code : <code> $query = "SELECT id, poin  FROM kualitas GROUP BY id";
$rst   = $mysqli->query($query);
          
while($row = $rst->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)){
$data1y[]  = $row[1]; //1st poin
$data2y[]  = $row[1]; //should be 2nd poin, but only show 1st poin
$labelX[]  = $row[0]; //label for id  
} <code>

Comment: @KayanaDwi you need to add all of this information to the question, including the full table definition, and how you wish to determine what goes in first point, second point, etc.

Comment: @pala Ok..i will send more detail information soon

Comment: Don't waste your time trying to group here. The `GROUP BY id` will result in one row per ID with a random `poin` for each ID. Run it in the command line or MySQL Workbench and you'll see. Your PHP code is off too: you're assigning `$row[1]` be data point 1y *and* data point 2y. Get the query right first, then you'll be able to fix the PHP code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php mysql query jpGraph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282819/php-mysql-query-jpgraph)